# Is “vorlagen” a form of “vorliegen”?

Tags: verb, tense

I could find no conjugation of any close verbs that include *vorlagen*.  I found somewhere a mention of a *subordinate clause* form of *vorliegen*, which I had never heard of before and can find no reference to in any of my books.

The clause in question is:

> Da bis zum Zeitpunkte der ersten Beobachtungen von Feindhandlungen weder besondere Feindmeldungen vorlagen, …

The rest of the sentence is quite long but if needed for context I can add it.

Clarification on the meaning/form of *vorlagen* would be greatly appreciated as well as direction to information on subordinate clause forms of verbs (that apparently are not included in the conjugation in *501 German Verbs*) would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don’t have the resource, but you should check whether *liegen* is included in the *501 German Verbs*.

Answer (score 7):

*Vorlagen* is the past *Präteritum* of vorliegen, 1st and 3rd persons in plural. It has no relation whatsoever with subordinate clauses.

What you might have done: Check if the verb is separable – you might want to learn the prefixes that make a verb separable. For two-part-verbs, (as in this case), then look up the conjugation of the root.

Answer (score 2):

There are no German verb forms that are exclusive to subordinate clauses.

However, there are irregular German verbs, often called *strong verbs* (*starke Verben*). These are typically characterised by a change of the stem vowel in the different tenses. In this case, *vorliegen* behaves exactly like *liegen* (*vorliegen* is also separable, so the present tense is ‘es liegt vor’, which shows the relation) and *liegen* is a strong verb.

> Ich l**ie**ge.
>
> Ich l**a**g.
>
> Ich bin gel**e**gen. (*habe gelegen* in the North)